# SELECT in UPDATE in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

my MYSQL Database looks like this:

> short -- idnumber--position
>
> abc.......8765...........4
>
> def........7453...........1
>
> abc.......7398...........5
>
> def........7542...........2

I have the idnumber and want to Update all with the the same 'short' as the idnumber. Update should be Position-1.

i have idnumber: 8765 its position should be 3 and position of id 7398 should be 4

How do i do it correctly? My Code dont work and i got no echo

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb1', 'root', '');

    $idV = $_GET['id'];

$statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE idtabelle SET position = position-1 WHERE short IN
(SELECT short FROM idtabelle WHERE idnumber = :idV)");
$statement->bindParam(':idV', $idV);
$statement->execute();

while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  echo $row['short'];
};
?>
```

Comment: You are running an `update`. Nothing to fetch..

Answer (score 0):

try this. you can give a start id.

```
UPDATE idtabelle
SET position = position -1 
WHERE idnumber = 8765
AND position > 2
ORDER BY position ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to fetch a row result from an UPDATE statement which doesn't return rows.   (Your SELECT subquery is returning it's rows only to the UPDATE query -- the UPDATE result is the only thing returned to you.)

What you should be doing is something like:

```
...
$statement->bindParam(':idV', $idV);
if ($statement->execute())
    echo $statement->rowCount() . " rows updated";
else
    echo "Update failed with error: " .print_r($statement->errorInfo(), TRUE);
...
```

If you need to get the value of "short" in addition to updating, then you should probably do it as two queries instead - a SELECT to get "short", and an UPDATE to update the rows after.

Answer (score 0):

If i try to run your query on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47321) i get the error: "You can't specify target table 'idtabelle' for update in FROM clause".

But you can wrap your subquery into another subquery (derived table):

```sql
UPDATE idtabelle 
SET position = position-1
WHERE short IN (SELECT short FROM (
  SELECT short
  FROM idtabelle
  WHERE idnumber = :idV
) temp);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d88a/1